# Some errors occurred when package was compiling.(LINK ERROR)

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys, i just copy the codes , in the Chapter 10 of  book,' Mastering ROS for Robotics Programming', to my ros. The cmakelists file is written as followed,

---

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(seven_dof_arm_test)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cmake_modules
  interactive_markers
  moveit_core
  moveit_ros_perception
  moveit_ros_planning_interface
  pluginlib**
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
catkin_package(
)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(test_random_node src/test_random.cpp)
add_dependencies(test_random_node seven_dof_arm_test_generate_messages_cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_random_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 )
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

---

And the cpp file is shown as followed,

```
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "move_group_interface_demo", ros::init_options::AnonymousName);
  // start a ROS spinning thread
  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
  spinner.start();
  // this connecs to a running instance of the move_group node
  move_group_interface::MoveGroup group("arm");
  // specify that our target will be a random one
  group.setRandomTarget();
  // plan the motion and then move the group to the sampled target 
  group.move();
  ros::waitForShutdown();
}
```

---

Now when the package is compiling, the error occured ,

```
Linking CXX executable /home/aicrobo/catkin_ws/devel/lib/seven_dof_arm_test/test_random_node
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/libmoveit_planning_scene_monitor.so: undefined reference to `ros::WallTimer::setPeriod(ros::WallDuration const&, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/aicrobo/catkin_ws/devel/lib/seven_dof_arm_test/test_random_node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [seven_dof_arm_test/CMakeFiles/test_random_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed
```

---

So do you have any idea about the problem? Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271431/some-errors-occurred-when-package-was-compiling.(link-error)/) by [pdmike](https://answers.ros.org/users/32007/pdmike/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the solution in [https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/703]

---

Originally posted by [pdmike](https://answers.ros.org/users/32007/pdmike/) with karma: 43 on 2017-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fully understand your frustration here and this should "just work" - and usually does so.

I can't see anything wrong with your code this far.

Shots in the dark:

- Did you add all the packages you `find_package` as `COMPONENTS` as `<build_depend>` in the corresponding package.xml? I found this has an influence on ordering of libraries in the build process and can induce weird linking problems. `catkin_lint` is your friend here.
- Are you sure your system is ok? Does it work on a different machine?

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-09-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pdmike](https://answers.ros.org/users/32007/pdmike/) on 2017-09-26**:
Hey dude,
Thank your for your reply. And i am new in the ROS. I just download Moveit by the command, `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit-full`.
I dont exactly know if the the packages  find_package as COMPONENTS as <build_depend> in the corresponding package.xml.
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend><build_depend>cmake_modules</build_depend><build_depend>interactive_markers</build_depend><build_depend>moveit_core</build_depend><build_depend>moveit_ros_perception</build_depend><build_depend>moveit_ros_planning_interface</build_depend><build_depend>pluginlib</build_depend><build_depend>roscpp</build_depend><build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend><run_depend>cmake_modules</run_depend><run_depend>interactive_markers</run_depend><run_depend>moveit_core</run_depend><run_depend>moveit_ros_perception</run_depend><run_depend>moveit_ros_planning_interface</run_depend><run_depend>pluginlib</run_depend><run_depend>roscpp</run_depend><run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-09-26**:
Hm, if this is part of your corresponding package.xml file, this should be fine too...
I'm sorry, I can't see anything wrong with your package at the moment.
Are you sure your system (which one?) is actually ok?